# Vue Get value from GET php

Tags: php, vue.js

I have this  for getting userType

```
<?php echo $userType = $_GET['user_type']?>;
```

I would like to initialize the $userType  to Vue varibale like below or any easy way available

```
var ArtificialInsemination = new Vue({

    el:'#ArtificialInsemination',
    data: {
        url:'http://localhost/dairyweb/dairyfarm/index.php',
        artificialInseminationRecords: [],
        cowId: '',
        aiNo: '',
        sessession:'',
        user:$userType

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue you can grab url parameters like this:

```
this.$route.query.user_type
```

Assuming your url is like this:

```
http:://example.com?user_type=exampletype
```

I'd also assume that you need to import the vuerouter, but i'm not 100% sure of that.